# Descargar imagen si no existe, y si existe, usar la memoria interna

Tags: java, android, imagen

Muy buenas. Estoy realizando una app que gestiona tickets y sus fotos. Y como no, tengo un problemilla.

El tema es que Android optimiza el espacio y el consumo de datos, y por lo tanto, si existe la foto almacenada ya no la descarga. Esto me perjudicaba mucho, ya que si la foto cambia, pero no el nombre, no se actualizaba la foto. Esto sucede usando el plugin de Fresco.

Así que obligué a descargar siempre las fotos mediante:

```
        imagePipeline.evictFromMemoryCache(url);
        imagePipeline.evictFromDiskCache(url);
        imagePipeline.evictFromCache(url);
```

Esto evita que se guarde en la caché del disco, o simplemente no lo guarda en el almacenamiento interno.
El problema que tengo ahora, es que siempre está consumiendo datos y descargando fotos cuando no es necesario. Además, los móviles más antiguos manifiestan problemas.

Para solucionar el problema, he pensado en esta solución: recibo de la API el peso de la foto, y la idea sería comprobar si coincide el peso. Si difiere, entonces significa que debe descargarse de nuevo la foto.

Mis dudas salen en cómo hacer este proceso. De momento quitando el bloque anterior de código y añadiendo este funciona:

```
    ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
    boolean inMemoryCache = imagePipeline.isInBitmapMemoryCache(imgUri);

    DataSource<Boolean> res2 = imagePipeline.isInDiskCache(imgUri);
```

El funcionamiento es correcto. La primera vez todos me devuelven un null o un false, y la segunda vez reconocen que está en la memoria y me devuelve un true. También supongo que si pongo evictFromCache, el booleano inMemoryCache tendría que devolver siempre false. Ya lo provaré.

Ahora que ya se gestiona mas o menos bien el tema de guardar la imagen, tendría que saber donde se almacena. Pero he buscado en muchas carpetas del móvil donde hago pruebas y no la encuentra. Al menos la foto que está almacenada en caché en la memoria interna debería salir, ¿no?

Necesito saber dónde se almacena para saber su peso y poder hacer la comprobación. Pero ni aparece, ni tampoco puedo conseguir información a través de imagePipeline ni tampoco de la propia vista.

Agradecería un poco de ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la solución al problema. Puede ser que alguno de los detalles que describa no sea del todo correcto, pero en general, el procedimiento sí lo es.

Mi premisa: comparar el tamaño de la foto almacenada en la caché con el tamaño de la imagen guardada en el servidor. Si difieren los tamaños, quiere decir que no es la misma foto, y por lo tanto, se tiene que descargar de nuevo.

La dificultad reside en conseguir el tamaño de la imagen guardada en la caché, que aparentemente no se puede conseguir. Pero lo que sí se puede, es borrar la imagen de la caché.

Entonces, el procedimiento es el siguiente: cada vez que se inicia la app, se descarga la foto en la caché. Y se borra cuando termina la app. 
Pues bien, ahora también se elimina de la caché cuando haces una foto nueva, mediante este código:

```
    imagePipeline.evictFromMemoryCache(url);
    imagePipeline.evictFromDiskCache(url);
    imagePipeline.evictFromCache(url);
```

Luego, cuando quieres ver los detalles del ticket con la foto, efectivamente se la descarga de nuevo porque no tiene la foto en la caché.

Para que esto funcione, necesitamos darle una Uri con el mismo nombre. En mi caso, utilizo el número de id.

Gracias por los que me han leído. Espero que mi aportación sirva a alguien.

SALUDOS